# You're being Cryptex!

Tags: knowledge, wordplay

Loop around, bottom to top until they all align.

Rotate to reveal the magic words in each line.

Once you knock everything out of the park,

With these seven lines you can make your mark.

[image]

Hint 1:

> Each of the line contain a single object (word or phrase).

Hint 2:

> Move the letters up and down/bottom to top only.

Hint 3:

> All 7 objects/components when combined are used to make a mark.

Hint 4:

> Parts of a device that puts mark on paper

Hint 5:

> Printers, Copiers, Electrophotography

Edit: Added hints. Updated the image using @kristinalustig's handy little tool.

Comment: Feel like adding a hint? :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the final arrangement, with the help of Kristina's excellent tool: if you like this answer, please upvote hers. (And I would suggest that @coredump give *this* answer the green checkmark and *Kristina's* answer the bounty.)

> [image]

The highlighted words are

> parts of a photocopier. (Taking "parts" a little broadly in the case of CHARGE.)

Answer (score 6):

I don't have a full answer, but I have a partial direction as well as a tool that folks can use to work on it themselves.

Here's where I think this is going:

> I think the directions are telling us to first adjust the letters side to side (from the bottom-up) in order to align something. And then to adjust the letters in each column up and down to find some words in the rows.

And here's the tool (no spoilers *really* but behind a tag anyway):

> https://codepen.io/kristinamay/full/gOPgPgg is a link to a cryptex "solver" tool I wrote that lets you move letters up, down, left, and right. Hopefully someone else can make use of it!

Comment: Nice! I may have jumbled the order of some of the letters such that not all words will be formed at the same time. Ooops. Used your nifty code to update. =)

Comment: @coredump Just to clarify, is it now the case that all words _are_ formed at the same time?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Aye and I see you already got em =)

Comment: Hah, I feel less bad that I was unable to figure this out, then, given that the letters were a bit out of order. 